# Divide beta from a gamma distribution to get another gamma distribution?

Tags: probability, self-study, density-function, gamma-distribution

In the textbook, there's a distribution like the following,

$S=\sum_{i=}^{200}X_i\sim Gamma(\alpha = 200, \beta)$

then the textbook define a new function $P$ obtained by diving the $\beta$, so something like:

$W=\frac{S}{\beta}\sim Gamma(\alpha = 200, 1)$

But why?? Are we allow to do this and keep it as a gamma distribution?

Edit:
Suppose  $P(S< 200\beta)$, will this equal to $P(W < 200\beta )$ or $P(W < 200)$ ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, when Gamma distribution is still in the same form if you (positively) [scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#/Scaling) it. Intuitively, exponential distribution can be thought of time needed for an event to occur, where Gamma can be thought of the same event occurring $\alpha$ times. The scaling we do here acts like just a unit change, e.g. seconds to hours.

For your second question, you just substitute their definitions:
$$P(S<200\beta)=P\left(\frac{S}{\beta}<200\right)=P(W<200)$$